# Force-Click in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm pretty new to IntelliJ, I also have Apple's new force-click enabled trackpad. Seems like it'd be super useful to be able to assign force-clicking to a keymap action (like bringing up a javadoc for example). Is there anyway to do this? Right now if I try to assign a force click it comes up as 'Button 1'.

Thanks!

Comment: I think in time this would happen in an update but currenty I suspect the action is too new or too specific to one vendor to be (easily) defined by JetBrains.

Comment: Try getting in touch with JetBrains and requesting it for an update?

Comment: Please, report your feature request to JetBrains (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us). This is not a question for stack overflow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This seems to be supported now in at least 2016.2, but you have to set it up.

For instance to set Force Touch to trigger "Go to Declaration" (navigate to function/class/symbol declaration), go to Preferences->Keymap.   Then search for "Declaration".   Right click the entry and select "Add mouse shortcut".   In the popup, perform a force-touch hard-click.   Apply and you're done!

Comment: Great! So usefull!

Comment: That works! But you can't seem to add modifiers (such as Command) to the force-touch hard-click.